# I need helping removing the T from my XML field

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table that has 2 columns. One column is a smalldatetime and the other column is a smallint. The smallint represents minutes. I want to add the minutes to my existing datetime field and generate XML that has the format of MM-DD-YYY HH:MM:SS. Currently, I just get YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS.

```
create table #temp(dt smalldatetime, intmin smallint)
insert into #temp(dt,intmin)
select getdate(),631
select  DATEADD(minute,intmin,format(cast(dt as datetime), 'MM/dd/yyyy 
hh:mm:ss')) from #temp for xml path('Orders'),root('Order')
```

Output is :

```
<Order>
<Orders>2018-07-12T20:49:00</Orders>
</Order>
```

Comment: What's the problem with the `T` anyway? It's how XML datetimes are represented.

Comment: That's a Good Thing. That's the ISO8601 format which is the only standard representation for a date in XML.

Comment: In fact you should *remove* the `format` call completely

Comment: I mean I get that it's the norm. But I was given requirements with a mock up XML by my boss and he said make it look like this. He doesn't care why or why not. He just wants what he wants. Can you help?

Comment: Standard is a lot stronger than "norm". Did your boss specifically say that he wants something unparseable by anyone including your company? In writing? In text that reads like "I want our customers to be unable to use our XML"? Signed and *notarized* ?

Comment: If he did, format the result of `dateadd`, not the `dt` value. And cancel any plans for the weekend because guess who'll get the call about the broken clients

Comment: I appreciate the feedback I guess? Not sure why you felt the need to be sarcastic. I've seen plenty of XML with datetime information that has never had the 'T' in the middle. But okay thanks anyway.

Comment: It's not sarcasm, it's a warning about writing bad, non-standard code. Every time you do that, there's someone down the line that will do it differently and things will explode. It's like the Mars Climate Orbiter that disintegrated on arrival at the red planet because two teams were working in metric and imperial.

Comment: @EricHathcock it's not sarcasm. Bad data like this means someone else will have to fix the mess. Someone's code will break because of the bad data. It's something that could lead to very serious business issues if somehow the bad data escapes and gets parsed incorrectly. It's also a great way to fail any XML interview questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CONVERT` to `VARCHAR` 120

DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME = GETDATE()

```
SELECT
     @DateTime
FOR XML PATH
```

Output

```
<row>2018-07-12T16:09:53.730</row> --Includes a T
```

Now remove the T

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, @DateTime, 120)
FOR XML PATH
```

Output

```
 <row>2018-07-12 16:09:53.730</row>  --T removed
```

Comment: No need for that. `Format` works just fine *if applied to the correct value*

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.